# ¿Cómo puedo mostrar una propiedad de un objeto dentro de un objeto en un repeater?

Tags: c#

Tengo una lista de Medicamentos que carga bien, muestra el código y su nombre pero al momento de mostrar el nombre de la farmacéutica no me lo muestra.

```
<script runat="server">
</script>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
    <style type="text/css">
        .style3
        {
            height: 17px;
        }
    </style>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <h3>
        Consulta los medicamentos en BiosFarma
    </h3>
    <p>
        ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    </p>
    <table style="width: 100%;">
        <tr>
            <td class="style3">
                &nbsp;
            </td>
            <td class="style3">
                &nbsp;
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Listar Medicamentos" />
                <asp:Repeater ID="RpMedicamento" runat="server" OnItemCommand="Repeater1_ItemCommand">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <table>
                            <tr bgcolor="#1d25d1">
                                <td>
                                    Codigo:<asp:TextBox ID="txtcodigo_medicamento" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Codigo_medicamento") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                    <br />
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    Nombre:<asp:TextBox ID="txtnombre_med" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Nombre_medi") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                    <br />
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    Nombre de farmaceutica:<asp:TextBox ID="TxtNomFarmaceutica" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind(**"Una_farm.Nombre_farm"**) %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                    <br />
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" CommandName="Seleccion" Style="text-align: center"
                                        Text="Seleccion" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <AlternatingItemTemplate>
                        <table>
                            <tr bgcolor="#57b65f">
                                <td>
                                    Codigo:<asp:TextBox ID="Txtncodigo" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Codigo_medicamento") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                    <br />
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    Nombre:<asp:TextBox ID="Txtnombre" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Nombre_medi") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                    <br />
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    Nombre de farmaceutica:<asp:TextBox ID="TxtNomFarmaceutica" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Una_farm") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                    <br />
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" CommandName="Seleccion" Style="text-align: center"
                                        Text="Seleccion" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </AlternatingItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
                <br />
                <br />
                <asp:Label ID="lblinfo" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                <br />
            </td>
            <td>
                &nbsp;
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Xml ID="controlXml" runat="server" TransformSource="~/XSLT/Medicamento.xslt"
                    ViewStateMode="Enabled"></asp:Xml>
            </td>
            <td>
                &nbsp;
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                &nbsp;
            </td>
            <td>
                &nbsp;
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</asp:Content>
```

La clase Medicamento:

```
public class Medicamento
{
    private int codigo_medicamento;
    private string nombre_medi;
    private string descripcion;
    private string tipo;
    private decimal precio;
    private int stock;
    private Farmaceutica una_farm;

    //[DataMember]
    public int Codigo_medicamento
    {
        get { return codigo_medicamento; }
        set { codigo_medicamento = value; }
    }
    //[DataMember]
    public string Nombre_medi
    {
        get { return nombre_medi; }
        set
        {
            if (value.Length < 3 || value.Length > 50)
                throw new Exception("Error: el nombre del medicamento debe ser entre 3 y 50 caracteres");
            else
                nombre_medi = value;
        }
    }

    //[DataMember]
    public string Descripcion
    {
        get { return descripcion; }
        set
        {
            if (value.Length < 3 || value.Length > 100)
                throw new Exception("Error: la descripción debe ser entre 3 y 100 caracteres.");
            else
                descripcion = value;
        }
    }

    public string Tipo
    {
        get { return tipo; }
        set
        {
            //if (value.Length < 3 || value.Length > 100)
            //    throw new Exception("Error: la descripcion debe ser entre 3 y 100 caracteres.");
            //else
            //    tipo = value;
            if (value == "Diabetico" || value == "Cardiologico" || value == "Otro")
                tipo = value;
            else
                throw new Exception("Error: El tipo es incorrecto");
        }
    }

    //[DataMember]
    public decimal Precio
    {
        get { return precio; }
        set
        {
            if (value < 0 || value > 99999999)
                throw new Exception("Error: el precio debe ser mayor a 0.");
            else
                precio = value;
        }
    }

    //[DataMember]
    public int Stock
    {
        get { return stock; }
        set
        {
            if (value <= 0 || value > 99999999)
                throw new Exception("Error: el stock debe ser mayor o igual a 0.");
            else
                stock = value;
        }
    }
    //[DataMember]
    public Farmaceutica Una_farm
    {
        get { return una_farm; }
        set
        {
            if (value == null)
                throw new Exception("Error: debe asignarse una farmacéutica");
            else
                una_farm = value;
        }
    }

    public Medicamento() { }

    public Medicamento(int cod, string nom, string descr, string tipo, decimal precio, int st, Farmaceutica farm)
    {
        Codigo_medicamento = cod;
        Nombre_medi = nom;
        Descripcion = descr;
        Tipo = tipo;
        Precio = precio;
        Stock = st;
        Una_farm = farm;
    }

}
```

}

La clase Farmaceutica

```
public class Farmaceutica
{
    //atributos
    private string nombre_farm;
    private string direccion;
    private string telefono;
    private string email;

    //propiedades
    //[DataMember]
    public string Nombre_farm
    {
        get { return nombre_farm; }
        set {if (value.Length < 3 || value.Length > 50)
            throw new Exception("Error: el nombre de la farmacia debe ser entre 3 y 50 caracteres");
        else
            nombre_farm = value; }
    }

    //[DataMember]
    public string Direccion
    {
        get { return direccion; }
        set
        {
            if (value.Length < 3 || value.Length > 50)
                throw new Exception("Error: la dirección debe ser entre 3 y 50 caracteres");
            else
                direccion = value;
        }
    }

    //[DataMember]
    public string Telefono
    {
        get { return telefono; }
        set
        {
            if (value.Length < 3 || value.Length > 50)
                throw new Exception("Error: el teléfono debe ser entre 3 y 50 números");
            else
                telefono = value;
        }
    }

    //[DataMember]
    public string Email
    {
        get { return email; }
        set
        {
            if ((value==null)&&(!Regex.IsMatch(value,"^(([\\w-]+\\.)+[\\w-]+|(([a-zA-Z]{1}|[\\w-]{2,}))@(([a-zA-Z]+[\\w.]+\\.){1,2}[a-zA-Z]{2,4})$")))
                throw new Exception("Error: el email debe ser de 3 a 50 y debe tener ser xxxx@xxx.xxx");
            else
                email = value;
        }
    }

    public Farmaceutica() { }

    public Farmaceutica(string nombre_farm, string direccion, string telefono, string email)
    {

        Nombre_farm = nombre_farm;
        Direccion = direccion;
        Telefono = telefono;
        Email = email;
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Podrias ser mucho mas claro con lo que necesitas y cual es el problema?

Comment: La verdad que no salió redactada como quise. 
En resumen  es la línea siguiente la que me da problemas:
      Nombre de farmaceutica:<asp:TextBox ID="TxtNomFarmaceutica" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Una_farm.Nombre_farm") %>'></asp:TextBox>
"Una_farm.Nombre_farm" no parece ser la sintáxis correcta, no puedo acceder a la propiedad.

Answer (score 0):

En el template deberias usar `Eval()`

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TxtNomFarmaceutica" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Una_farm.Nombre_farm") %>'></asp:TextBox>
```

[DataBinder.Eval Method](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.databinder.eval?view=netframework-4.5)

la interpretacion dle binding el el Eval() evalua mejor las propiedades compuestas

Comment: Sí, había probado el Eval y no sale nada.

Comment: estas seguro que asignas bien los datos de la entidad relacionada? despues de cargar la lista que asignas el Datasource del Repeater evalua si tiene datos. Revisa el codigo de como cargas la entidad

Comment: Sí, carga datos. En el repeater el dato que no sale es el del nombre de la farmacéutica. Si pongo Eval("Una_farm") en el repeater sale: "EntidadesCompartidas.Farmaceutica"

Comment: Estaba comentado un buscar, era por eso que no cargaba los datos, estaba bien el código. Gracias por la ayuda.